# Query Active Directory Status by User's Email

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am facing a strange issue.
I want to know whether user's AD account is disabled or not by providing user's `email` as the parameter.

Below code is working great for me for some set of users in our Org.
But for some other set of users its returning `null`- though I can able to verify these set of users in AD manually.

Can you please help me to over come from this issue.

```
        private string GetCurrentDomainPath()
        {
            DirectoryEntry de =
               new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");

            return "LDAP://" +
               de.Properties["defaultNamingContext"][0].
                   ToString();
        }

        public bool? FindAccountStatusByEmail(string email)
        {
            using (DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry(GetCurrentDomainPath())))
            {
                dSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                dSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=*)(mail=" + email.Trim() + "))";
                SearchResult sResult = dSearch.FindOne();
                if (sResult != null)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry de = sResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                    return IsActive(de);
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        private bool IsActive(DirectoryEntry de)
        {
            if (de.NativeGuid == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            int flags = (int)de.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;

            return !Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002);
        }
```

**Update-1:** Lets say I have one user's email address : `abac@mydomain.com`
When I passing this email address through the code, its returning `null`.
But when I am searching it in through windows provided tool(Find Users,Contacts and Groups) I am able to retrieve the user.
[image]

But just now noticed that in "E-mail :" section that user's email is different
say `abac@mydomainlbs.com` in the above picture.

Comment: Maybe i dont get u right but if the user has no e-Mail-Address assigned your FindAccountStatusByEmail will always return null & never check viaIsActive()

Comment: @Cadburry: I can confirm their email is prenent

Comment: What if you change the dSearch.Filter and only filter by the mailproperty? Not by ObejctCategory and so on.. Dont you get the directory-Entries or is the Properties["userAccountControl"] null?

Comment: @Cadburry: I have change the filter to `dSearch.Filter = "(&(mail=" + email.Trim() + "))";` But in `SearchResult sResult = dSearch.FindOne();` sResult  is getting `null`

Comment: hmm - is it just One Domain-Controller? (replication-problem)  - Are you  able to find the expected users if you search on the server (dsa.msc - ActiveDirectoryUsersAndCOmputers) & filter by the mailproperty as you do it in the code? Are you executing this one on a client or at the server?